# list to data frame specifying column names

Tags: r

```
a <- list()
a[["product_1"]]$sales <- 100
a[["product_1"]]$stock <- 50
a[["product_2"]]$sales <- 200
a[["product_2"]]$stock <- 80
```

I want to convert to a data frame with columnames = "product" 
"sales" "stock"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is `map_dfr`

```
library(purrr)
map_dfr(a, as_tibble, .id = 'product')
```

---

Or with `bind_rows`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(a, .id = 'product')
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  sales stock product  
#* <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    
#1   100    50 product_1
#2   200    80 product_2
```

---

Or using `rbindlist` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(a, idcol = 'product')
#     product sales stock
#1: product_1   100    50
#2: product_2   200    80
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
do.call(rbind,  Map(cbind, lapply(a, as.data.frame), product = names(a)))
```